# Does windows OS brings some VC++ runtime by default?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am going to deploy a VC++ application to windows server 2016(datacenter). I am not sure if the OS already has the vc++ runtime I needed,  or I have to bring them with my application?  Where can I check such information,  like the default existed VC++ runtime for different Windows OS version?

Comment: If you don't have/want an installer then [use this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the distant past (Visual C++ 4 or so), there was an OS C/C++ Runtime (CRT) that caused a lot of [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

Visual C++ 2005/2008 used a 'Fusion side-by-side' solution for the (CRT) . This was intended to allow side-by-side application local as well as central servicing, but that turned out to have a lot of it's own problems

Visual C++ 2010, 2012, and 2013 had a simple 'install to the System32 folder' system-wide -or- 'place it side-by-side' application local style. If you use application local, then it's basically up to the application developers to update the copy they use for servicing.

Visual C++ 2015 is similar to the VS 2010/2012/2013 story, except that the C/C++ Runtime itself been [refactored](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/).

- A core part of the C Runtime is part of the OS as of Windows 10--with a downlevel version for older OSes handled as part of the VCREDIST packages--that is serviced via Windows Update. This is `UCRTBASE.DLL` which is referred to as the [Universal CRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/).
- The Visual C/C++ Runtime is deployed just as it was with the VS 2012/2013 story. It relies on the `UCRTBASE.DLL`. The Visual C++/C++ Runtime is tied to the specific release you are using of Visual C++.

Currently the VS 2015, VS 2017, and VS 2019 CRT are [binary compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) so you can mix code built with all three toolsets but you need to be linking against the newer Visual C/C++ Runtime library for everything to work.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deploying-native-desktop-applications-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)

> Note that one of the things the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) model takes care of for you is deploying the right copy of the Visual C/C++ Runtime via the Store. This is not so much 'included with the OS' as it is 'handled transparently on behalf of Windows Store apps'.

**UPDATE:** The binary compatible promise goes from VS 2015 Update 3 to VS 2022. Note that you are required to do the link with the *newest* toolset for this to work, and of course redistribute the *newest* version of the runtime DLLs.